# Can you change the functionality of the completed check box in a task list or remove it from content type?

Tags: tasks

The mark completed check box in SP2013 task list changes the % complete to 100.  This box is easily check by accident and then when you uncheck it changes the %complete to 0 no matter what it was before you checked the box.  I would like to either change the functionality or remove it from the content type.  Any suggestions??

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using List Settings you can modify the View and Remove Field "Completed".

This will hide that column from the View.